# button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a checkbox in my page

```
 <asp:CheckBox onclick="calc();" ID="chkfilteritem" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
```

and a button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnclick" runat="server" Text="." onclick="btnclick_Click" />
```

also i have a javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function calc() {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnclick %>').click();
   }
 </script>
```

what I need is when I check or uncheck the checkbox I need to fire a click event on the button using javascript.But it is not working with my current javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, do this:

```
<asp:CheckBox CssClass="checkFilter" ID="chkfilteritem" runat="server" Text="Yes" />

<asp:Button CssClass="buttonClick" ID="btnclick" runat="server" Text="." onclick="btnclick_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.checkFilter').on('change', function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         $('.buttonClick').click();
     }
 }
</script>
```

I'd say you could use `ClientIDMode="Static"` but I'm not sure if you're using your code in a re-usable control, which would mess things up.

You could also go down this route (far less readable, but it'll work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#<%=chkfilteritem.ClientID %>').on('change', function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         $('#<%=btnclick.ClientID %>').click();
     }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using Master Page

```
 document.getElementById('<%= btnclick.ClientID %>').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output of the ID's if using .NET 4+

```
<asp:CheckBox onclick="calc();" ID="chkfilteritem" runat="server" Text="Yes" />

<asp:Button ID="btnclick" runat="server" Text="." OnClick="btnclick_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function calc() {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnclick.ClientID %>').click();
  }
</script>
```

The click event should now fire.

The checkbox has a HTML onclick attribute, while the button has the .NET OnClick event.

An alternative would be to remove the HTML onlclick from the checkbox, add ClientIDMode="Static" to the checkbox and change the script to as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#chkfilteritem").click(function() {
      calc();
    });

  });

  function calc() {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnclick.ClientID %>').click();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: onclick is still a server routine, rather than client-side event. calc will never get fired from the checkbox using onclick.

Comment: thedixon - i've further clarified

Comment: Looks a whole lot like my answer now... ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to remove the ClientIDMode="Static" after reading yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnCheckedChanged event of checkbox and then check.

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox onclick="javascript:calc();" ID="chkfilteritem" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
```

Comment: Not what the OP is asking for